# What are the allophones of /ɹ/ in General Western English?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, american-english

What are the allophones of /ɹ/ in General Western English?

By General Western English, I mean the dialect of English that is spoken by people raised in Seattle, WA;   Portland, OR;  and other places west of the Cascade Mountains in the USA.

I have heard someone say that there are twelve, but I have been unable to confirm the number on the internet, and have not been able to find a specific list of them either.

Comment: The number of specific allophones depends on the granularity of the transcription. There could be a dozen in one system and two in a different one, and 234 in still a different one. The important thing is that each allophone have a specific environment that determines its necessity or possibility (for free variants) of occurrence. Without those, a list of phones is not a list of allophones.

Comment: **see:** (2010) Jeff Mielke, Adam Baker, and Diana Archangeli. Variability and homogeneity in American English /r/ allophony and /s/ retraction. Variation, Detail, and Representation. (LabPhon 10). Berlin: Mouton de Gruyter. 699-719.